# How can I migrate Gulp3 to Gulp4 (gulpfile.js)?

Tags: terminal, gulp, gulp-sass, postcss, gulp-4

Im having problems to update my gulpfile.js from GULP3 to GULP4
I tried to update with gulp.series() and gulp.parallel()
My Gulpfile is like this :

```
var gulp = require('gulp')
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create()

gulp.task('serve', function(){
  browserSync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: './dist'
    }
  })
})
gulp.task('css', function(){

  var processors = [
  //postcssPlugins
  ]

  return gulp.src('./srcFiles')
    .pipe(postcss(processors))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./DestFiles'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream())
})
gulp.task('watch', function(){
  gulp.watch('srcFiles', ['css'])
  gulp.watch('DestFile.Html').on('change', browserSync.reload)
})
gulp.task('default', ['watch', 'serve'])
```

The error I get is `Task function must be specified`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of significant differences between Gulp 3 and Gulp 4 that you need to be aware of. For instance, Gulp.js 4.0 introduces the series() and parallel() methods to combine tasks:

- series(...) runs tasks one at a time in the order specified, and
- parallel(...) runs tasks simultaneously in any order.

For a complete walk-through of how to set up your gulpfile.js in Gulp 4, I recommend the detailed tutorial found at [Coder Coder](https://coder-coder.com/gulp-4-walk-through/).

Meanwhile, a quick re-write of your code would roughly look something like this...

```
var gulp = require("gulp"),
    browserSync = require("browser-sync").create();

var paths = {
    styles: {
        src: "./path/to/scss/files/**/*.scss",
        dest: "./folder/to/output/css/file"
    }
}

function css(){
    return gulp
        .src(paths.styles.src)
        // ... CSS Preprocessor Plugins
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.styles.dest))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
}

function reload(){
    browserSync.reload();
}

function watch(){
    browserSync.init({
        server: { baseDir: "./dist" }
    });
    gulp.watch(paths.styles.src, css);
    gulp.watch('DestFile.html', reload);
}

exports.watch = watch;
exports.css = css;
exports.default = gulp.parallel(css, watch);
```

All you would then need to do is run `gulp` or `gulp watch` to initialize the BrowserSync server and begin watching for changes.

If you need to only recompile the CSS, you could run `gulp css`.

To see the list of gulp tasks available, run `gulp --tasks`.